# Finding pairs closer than a given distance (proximity) in a set of points

Tags: node.js, algorithm, indexing, nearest-neighbor

I'm developping a multiplayer game with node.js. Every second I get the coordinates (X, Y, Z) of every player. How can I have, for each player a list of all players located closer than a given distance from him ?

Any idea to avoid a O(n²) calculation?

Comment: Try searching for "Nearest neighbor search". Specifically look at octrees or Kd-trees, I find them to be easier to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I have the answer now. Thanks to  G. Samaras and Anony-Mousse:
I use a kd-tree algorithm:

- First I build the tree with all the players
- Then for each player I calculate the list of all the players within given range arround this player

This is very fast and easy with the npm module kdtree: https://www.npmjs.org/package/kdtree

```
var kd = require('kdtree');
var tree = new kd.KDTree(3); // A new tree for 3-dimensional points
var players = loadPlayersPosition(); // players is an array containing all the positions
for (var p in players){ //let's build the tree
    tree.insert(players[p].x, players[p].y, players[p].z, players[p].username);
}

nearest = [];    
for (var p in players){ //let's look for neighboors
    var RANGE = 1000; //1km range
    close = tree.nearestRange(players[p].x, players[p].y, players[p].z, RANGE);
    nearest.push(close);
}
```

It returns `nearest` that is an array conataining for each player all his neighboors within a range of 1000m. I made some tests on my PC with 100,000 simulated players. It takes only 500 ms to build the tree and another 500 ms to find the nearest neigboors pairs. I find it very fast for such a big number of players.

bonus: if you need to do this with latitude and longitude instead of x, y, z,  just convert lat, lon to cartesian x, y z, because for short distances chord distance on a sphere ~ great circle distance

Answer (score 1):

You are not looking for clustering algorithms.

Instead, you are looking for a **database index** that supports radius queries.

Examples:

- R*-tree
- kd-tree
- M-tree
- Gridfile
- Octree (for 3d, quadtree for 2d)

Any of these should do the trick, and yield an `O(n log n)` performance theoretically. In practise, it's not as easy as this. If all your objects are really close, "closer than a given coordinate" may mean every object, i.e. O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a **quadtree** in 3 dimensions, i.e. an octree. An octree is basically the same as the binary tree, but instead of two children per node, it has 2^D = 2^3 = 8 children per node, where D is the dimension.

For example, imagine a cube. In order to create the next level of the root, you actually have every node representing the 8 sub-cubes inside the cube and so on.

This tree will yield fast lookups but careful not to use it for more dimensions. I had built a polymorphic quadtree and wouldn't go to more than 8-10 dimensions, because it was becoming too flat.

The other approach would be the **kd-tree**, where actually you halve the dataset (the players) at every step.

You could use a library that provides nearest neighbour searching.